# Loop em php de imagens com bootstrap

Tags: php, imagem, loop

Tenho este código que traz algumas imagens do Instagram, quero que fique 3 fotos por `row` (linha);

Depois se houver mais de 3, cria outra row.

meu codigo:

```
<div class="row">
                      <?php foreach ($insta_user->edge_owner_to_timeline_media->edges as $value): ?>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <?php
                      $return_user_insta = (object) [
                        'id'          => $value->node->id,
                        'display_url' => $value->node->display_url
                      ];
                      echo '<img src="' . $return_user_insta->display_url . '" class="img-fluid"';
                      ?>
                      </div>
                      <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>
```

Só que quando eu faço isso, apenas buga, e fica tudo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag `<img>` do seu código está sem fechamento. Acrescente um `>` no final que irá ficar assim:

```
echo '<img src="' . $return_user_insta->display_url . '" class="img-fluid">';
```

Comment: Eita.. que absurdo, falta de atenção... mas obrigado assim que der o tempo eu marco como resolvido ok?

Comment: Falta de atenção acontece muito. Coisas simples assim podem causar um problema que você quase não consegue resolver...

Comment: Outra coisa, aproveitando o post... o Bootstrap tem como configurar pra deixar algumas imagens ativas só em celular? sou novo com bootstrap

Comment: O boootstrap é para deixar o conteúdo responsivo em diversas resoluções... Se você quiser fazer com que a imagem apareça apenas no celular você deve criar uma classe e aplicá-la a propriedade @media (CSS) nela e fazer com que o estilo da classe se aplique apenas a determinado tamanho a resolução de tela